# What does it take to persuade people in Promises to Keep?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[Promises to Keep](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Promises_to_Keep): Help [Louis Letrush](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Louis_Letrush) get [Frost](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Frost) from [Sibbi Black-Briar](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sibbi_Black-Briar).

In this quest, there are multiple chances to persuade people (the guard and Sibbi, twice). How much Speech is required to successfully persuade them?

The reason that I phrased the title so, instead of as "how much Speech do I need to persuade...", is because I know that the [Amulet of Articulation](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Amulet_of_Articulation) is an alternative to Speech, thus there are alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Both persuading the guard to let you in and persuading Sibbi to give you the key are Easy speech checks. They require 25 speech, or 18 speech and the Persuasion perk.